# F-test for Lack-of-Fit in SPSS

Tags: regression, anova, spss

Some googling revealed that doing the F-test for Lack-of-Fit in SPSS is not so trivial. It seems one has to “trick” SPSS to do that. See for example [this](http://www.math.umt.edu/olear/STAT458/Lab%205.pdf). Can anybody suggest a better source of information on how this can be done? I have SPSS 16. Of course I know it can be easily done using R but I am interested in the SPSS way.

Thanks

Comment: Of course now the SPSS way can also be the R way: "Starting with Version 16, SPSS offers a free plug-in that lets users run R code within SPSS having full access to the active SPSS Statistics data, and writing its output to the SPSS Statistics Viewer" (http://insideout.spss.com/2009/01/13/spss-statistics-and-r/)

Comment: Your link seems like it explains it fairly well, gd. It's a little verbose, but it does the job. If you really feel most comfortable in R and need the output in SPSS, DrNexus' suggestion about the SPSS-R connection is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use SPSS for the Lack of fit test go to: Analyze>>Compare Means>>Means.

Then in the dialogue box that appears assign your Independent and Dependent Variables. Select Options and a new dialogue box will appear. Check the option at the bottom of the screen that says "Test for Linearity".