# F-test for lack of fit using R

Tags: r, regression

How do I test for Lack Of Fit (F-test) using R? I've seen a similar question, but that was for SPSS and it was just said that is can be easily done in R, but not how.

I know in simple linear regression I would use `anova(fm1,fm2)`, `fm1` being my model, `fm2` being the same model with `x` as a factor (if there are several `y` for `x`).
How do I do it in multiple linear regression?

Comment: Can you say which CV question you are referring to? Note that an ANOVA is a multiple regression model, just one w/ only categorical covariates. In R, the code / formulation should be identical for performing a nested model test b/t 2 ANOVA's & 2 MR's.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4762/f-test-for-lack-of-fit-in-spss is the one I was talking about

Answer (score 2):

As @gung says in the comment, your question title and text conflict. The F-test for joint significance of all parameters in a model is on a *single* model fit; it is displayed each time you do `summary()`.

Comparisons of models is a whole different ball game -- as the models need to be nested for inference to be valid.

The [lmtest](http://cran.r-project.org/package=lmtest) adds a number of common econometrics tests for linear models. As an illustration, here is the beginning of `examples(lrtest)` for using a likelihood-ratio test to compare two nested models:

```
R>      ## with data from Greene (1993):
R>      data("USDistLag")
R>      usdl <- na.contiguous(cbind(USDistLag, lag(USDistLag, k = -1)))
R>      colnames(usdl) <- c("con", "gnp", "con1", "gnp1")
R>      fm1 <- lm(con ~ gnp + gnp1, data = usdl)
R>      fm2 <- lm(con ~ gnp + con1 + gnp1, data = usdl)
R>      lrtest(fm2, fm1)
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: con ~ gnp + con1 + gnp1
Model 2: con ~ gnp + gnp1
  #Df LogLik Df Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
1   5 -56.07                        
2   4 -65.87 -1 19.61   9.52e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
R>
```

Comment: What I want to do is test a model for Lack Of Fit. I do not want to compare it, I just read that it is done this way. That seems to be not true. So the question is: how do I test my multiple regression model for lack of fit?

Comment: You can look at `summary(lm(y ~ . , data=X))` which prints the F-test for you.

Comment: but that is f-test for different variables, not for the whole model. am I wrong?

Comment: Well, I fear you are wrong. The F-test corresponds to testing all variables at the same time, and as such can be seen as a test of the whole model.  You may want to check the documentation of the `lmtest` package as well as the references it offers.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel The F-test is not the lack of fit test !

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Would you provide an example of a lack of fit test?  This seems to be a common misconception: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287532/r-lack-of-fit-test-via-anova

Comment: @rpierce Sorry I don't remember... I only remember this is something well-known in DOE.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the lack-of-fit test with the `alr3` package.

```
> library(alr3)
> x1 <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4)
> x2 <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3)
> y <- rnorm(10, x1+x2)
> fit <- lm(y ~ x1+x2)
> pureErrorAnova(fit)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
             Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
x1            1  8.6412  8.6412  53.857 0.08622 .
x2            1 11.9019 11.9019  74.180 0.07359 .
Residuals     7 10.8198  1.5457                  
 Lack of fit  6 10.6593  1.7766  11.073 0.22608  
 Pure Error   1  0.1604  0.1604                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Note the equivalence here:

```
> xx1 <- factor(x1)
> xx2 <- factor(x2)
> fit1 <- lm(y ~ xx1*xx2)
> anova(fit, fit1)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y ~ x1 + x2
Model 2: y ~ xx1 * xx2
  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1      7 10.8198                           
2      1  0.1604  6    10.659 11.073 0.2261
```